# How do I search through multiple fields in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to search or filter through 3 fields *firstname, lastname* and *email* in my Vue.js 2 application. I understand that Vue 2 does not come with a built in filter method unlike in Vue 1, hence I created a custom method which is only able to filter through just one field. How do I extend this to multiple fields? I have tried something like this `filterBy(list, value1, value2, value3)` but it does not work.

This is my code

```
<template>
<div class="customers container">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" v-
model="filterInput">
<br />
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="customer in filterBy(customers, filterInput)">
      <td>{{customer.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
      <td><router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/customer/'+customer.id">View</router-link></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
name: 'customers',
data () {
return {

  customers: [],
  filterInput:'',

}
},

methods: {
fetchCustomers(){
  this.$http.get('http://slimapp.dev/api/customers')
    .then(function(response){

      this.customers = (response.body); 
    });
 },

 filterBy(list, value){
    value = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    return list.filter(function(customer){
      return customer.last_name.indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
  },


  },

  created: function(){
  if (this.$route.params.alert) {
  this.alert = $route.params.alert
  }
  this.fetchCustomers();
  },

  updated: function(){
  this.fetchCustomers();
  },
  components: {

  }
  }
  </script>

  <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
  <style scoped>
```

Comment: You could take a look at this vue plugin - https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend your filterBy method to check more then just last_name

```
filterBy(list, value){
    value = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    return list.filter(function(customer){
      return customer.first_name.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
             customer.last_name.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
             customer.email.indexOf(value) > -1
    });
  },
```

But you can use computed to provide filtered results (it might perform better because it caches computations)

```
computed: {
  filteredList() {
    const value= this.filterInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.filterInput.slice(1);
    return this.customers.filter(function(customer){
      return customer.first_name.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
             customer.last_name.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
             customer.email.indexOf(value) > -1
    })
  }
}
```

and use it in your template

```
<tr v-for="customer in filteredList">
 ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above method finds all strings STARTING with the word you are looking for and ignores all middle-sentence words.

This means that if you have a customer like `Vincent Van Patten` you will only find it by searching for `Vincent` or `Vincent(space)Van`. If you search for the word `Van` or `Patten` it will return an empty search because you are using `indexOf` inside filter.

This is why I would rather use JS `includes()`:

```js
computed: {
  filteredList() {
    const value= this.filterInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.filterInput.slice(1);
    return this.customers.filter(function(customer){
      return customer.first_name.includes(value) ||
             customer.last_name.includes(value) ||
             customer.email.includes(value)
    })
  }
}
```

Any search like `Van` or `Patten` will now match

Answer (score 0):

just to make it more flexibel do some lowercase:

```
computed: {
    filteredList() {
        const value = this.filterInput.toLowerCase().slice(1);
        return this.customers.filter(function(customer){
            return customer.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 ||
            customer.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 ||
            customer.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
        })
    }
}
```